# Use rsync to just get a folder and its content with a pattern

Tags: rsync, wildcards

I've looked all around the internet, looked in regexp sites and everything else, but I'm unable to write a rsync command to fetch what I want to.

I need to mirror the FreeBSD release, but I don't need the RC versions and BETA versions, so I just need to rsync any folder with RELEASE in it's name with all files and subfolders of this folder.

At this moment I've this command running without success:

```
rsync -vaz --delete --dry-run ftp2.br.freebsd.org::FreeBSD/releases/amd64 /usr/repos --include=".{0,}(RELEASE)" --filter="-! */"
```

Let's image the following folder structure:

```
amd64/8.3-RELEASE/
amd64/8.4-RC2/
amd64/amd64/10.0-RC5/
amd64/amd64/10.0-RELEASE/
amd64/amd64/9.1-RELEASE/
amd64/amd64/9.2-BETA1/
amd64/amd64/9.2-BETA2/
amd64/amd64/9.2-RC1/
```

In this case rsync should only get:

```
amd64/8.3-RELEASE/
amd64/amd64/10.0-RELEASE/
amd64/amd64/9.1-RELEASE/
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
$ rsync -vaz --delete --dry-run ftp2.br.freebsd.org::FreeBSD/releases/amd64 /usr/repos \
    --include="*RELEASE/***" --include="*/" --exclude="*" --prune-empty-dirs
```

I think it is what your after.